# Как перевести число из десятичной в 62-ричную систему счисления?

Tags: php, алгоритм, системы-счисления

Функция `base_convert` - поддерживает только 36-ричную систему.
62-ричная система счисления это: `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: делить искомое число на 62 и брать остаток пока число не станет ноль

Comment: не понятно, можно пример?

Comment: ну как вы обычно переводите число из 10 тичной, скажем в двоичную систему ?? это хоть помните ? если да то по тому же принципу только вместо двойки у вас 62

Comment: ого, а я думал каждой цифре просто присвоена комбинация нулей и единиц

Comment: Не знаю как автора вопроса, но меня переводить из любой системы счисления в любую систему счисления учили в школе на уроках информатики :\

Comment: @andreymal ну сейчас то я уже прочитал (правда сложно всё это). а в школе на информатике мы в cs играли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения вашего вопроса можно использовать эти две функции `php` ( `gmp_init`, `gmp_strval` ).

Эти функции можно использовать начиная с версии `PHP 5.3.2`.

И для этого нужно установить на сервере модуль `GMP`. Вот инструкция для установки модуля в `Linux`.

> 1. `apt-get install php5-gmp`
> 2. включите модуль в `php.ini` добавив в нем строку `extension=php_gmp.so`

А это пример кода с использованием этих функции для преобразования числа в 62 систему счисления.

```
<?php
  $hexadecimal = '37334';
  $a = gmp_init($hexadecimal);
  printf(gmp_strval($a,62));
?>
```

Подробнее о функциях прочитать можете здесь.

1. [gmp_init](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gmp-init.php)
2. [gmp_strval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gmp-strval.php)

Comment: Интересно почему base_convert не поддерживает 62?

Comment: @Hipster потому, что в шестнадцатеричной нотации, например, `0xff` полностью идентично `0xFF`

Comment: @rjhdby спасибо, но непонятно.

Comment: @Hipster эта функция регистронезависима. Т.е. не различает большие и маленькие буквы. Следовательно максимальная база - 36 (цифры + буквы). Сделано это потому, что в 99.9999% случаев используются только 4 системы счисления: двоичная, восьмеричная, десятичная и шестнадцатеричная. А 16-ричные числа задают кто в лес, кто по дрова - как большими буквами, так и маленькими.

Answer (score 3):

Вплоть до 36-ричной системы можно использовать штатную функцию [base_convert](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.base-convert.php)

Если хотите больше, то для начала необходимо определить словарь

```
$dictionary = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

Соответственно индекс символа в строке соответствует десятичному значению.

А потом, как в комментарии `ampawd`

```
$base = 62;
$input = 2317864864;
$output = '';

while($input > 0){
    $digit = $input % $base;
    $output = $dictionary[$digit].$output;
    $input = (int) ($input / $base);
}
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/562b0e193687e73f4a6b7af3b9a3aef6306d2e44)

Answer (score 1):

пример rjhdby  работает прекрасно. Вот обратная функция перевода

```
$output = '132g';
$input =0;
$cursor = 0; $maxcursor = strlen($output);
$result =0;

while ($cursor<$maxcursor) {
$curr=substr($output, $cursor,1);
echo "[";
echo $curr;
echo ":";
$digit = strpos($dictionary, $curr);
echo $digit;
echo "]";
$cursor = $cursor + 1;
$result = $result+pow(62,($maxcursor-$cursor))*$digit;
}
echo $result;
```